# How can I leverage my experience with the JVM and Android to do some hobby-level building and controlling robots at home?

Tags: software, wifi, platform

I'm looking for a product for home hobby-level robotics. Something that has modular robot hardware allowing me to design the robot itself, but lets me write the logic in a JVM or Android language. I have searched several times so I'm not expecting a big list, but it could be designed any of three ways that I can think of:

1. connects to a configurable API endpoint, OR conversely,

   - publishes an HTTP or RPC API for a controlling client to connect to, or
2. supports running a jar or apk on the robot itself, or
3. plugs into and carries around an Android device or small computer with some standard language-agnostic way of communicating with control APIs locally.

I'd like to dabble in robotics. The thing I know best is the JVM. For better or worse, I've worked almost exclusively with the JVM for over 10 years and know several JVM-based languages. Call me specialized, but I'm not investing full work days in developing a new skill, and if I can't lean on my familiarity with known tech, I would anticipate dipping a toe into robotics to be more frustrating than fun. I know the JVM is heavy for the low-cost, bare-metal architecture choices that are typically made in the field of robotics; let's not talk about that here.

Extra points if a kit comes with a Kotlin library.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Travis Well, but I'm afraid that opinion polls are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of different opinions are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: You've got your specifications; there's not really anything to answer here except to provide a list of items that you could find yourself by searching online.

Comment: @Chuck, as stated, I've searched. I also specifically asked NOT to discuss advantages and disadvantages. You clearly didn't read the question.

Comment: Sorry, it's a boilerplate closing message and I didn't edit that part appropriately. It should have read as it does now - `questions which ask for a list of different opinions are off-topic.` Case in point: You have two "answers," from the same user, **suggesting** different approaches. There is no correct answer because there is no answerable question. *There's nothing to teach here*, and that's the real reason why it's off-topic.

Comment: @Chuck how can you say there is nothing to teach, when I got two good answers that I learned from, and would not have found otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [LeJOS](http://www.lejos.org/)? It's a port of the Java VM and SDK to the various Lego MINDSTORMS robot kits. The Lego kits themselves are quite capable as hobbyist robotics kits go, I bought the NXT version years ago and had a lot of fun with it. The newest [EV3](https://www.lego.com/en-ca/product/lego-mindstorms-ev3-31313) kit has a powerful ARM CPU and an SD card reader for loading software, it looks like a good option if you don't want to spend much time fiddling around with firmware installation.

Comment: Thanks @xperroni! This looks like the perfect place to start. Also, I see why I didn't come across Pi4J and JArduino before, as they are not robot-specific. But I will bookmark them as the next step once I outgrow Mindstorms. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative are robots based on the Raspberry Pi or Arduino microcontrollers. The [Pi4J](https://pi4j.com/1.2/) library implements convenient API's for accessing Raspberry Pi I/O's, while the [JArduino](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino) distribution enables controlling Arduino boards from Java over a serial or Bluetooth connection. You can search for "arduino robot kit" or "raspberry pi robot kit" to find hobbyist kits based on those platforms.